# Ender Pearl Textures Not Showing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I edited my resource packs ender pearl texture by replacing the original texture with another ender pearl texture from a different pack and now whenever I see an ender pearl it is a pink and black checkered tile do I have to move anything else to change the ender pearls texture?

Comment: Is the texture right format, is it named properly, is its size power of two?

Comment: has the texture pack made a texture for the ender pearl?

Comment: Yes the pack had a ender pearl texture and I downloaded it again just to make sure that everything downloaded properly... same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably that the ender pearl you copied is the wrong resolution, standard minecraft is 16x16 but resourcepacks can go beyond this.

You can fix the resolution by:
Finding the resolution of the resource pack by selecting one of the other textures (but not any animated ones) in your file browser and using an image converter convert your ender pearl image to that resolution.

There are a bunch of image converters out there but I personaly use http://www.garyshood.com/imageconvert/ because I find the interface clear and it is quick.

Comment: Thanks I converted the image and it worked great thanks!